# What word would have been used in-place of 'even' during 17th century London

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

Good evening, I am in the midst of completing a time-placed stageplay and I am being exceedingly pronounced on its authenticity, in accordance with the language and word-choice, to the 1660s in London. Now, I have just realized that the word "even" was used a few times in my play with the later arisen context of the word meaning "to express something rather surprising or extraordinarily extreme": "**even** the power-lusty King's allies were at risk."

Now my question is, during 17th century London what word would have been used, commonly, which resonated the same context of our modern-day use of the word "even," which from what I have gathered meant, at the time, "equal" and "harmonious."

this is an example from my play with the word "even" which must be corrected:

"...and **even** they wouldst, shortly after, forget of what it did taste like"

Comment: [The Book of Common Prayer, 1635](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Book_of_Common_Prayer_With_the_Psalt/hkhnAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22even+the%22&pg=PR12-IA1&printsec=frontcover): 19 Praised be the Lord daily : *even* the God which helpeth us,and poureth his benefits upon us. 2o He is our God,*even* the God of whom comethfalvation: God is the Lord by whom we escape death.

Comment: You may wish to look at "power-lusty" - hyphenated words were uncommon in the 16th century. I suggest "even the King's allies, lusty of power, were imperilled"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the words of a man who actually wrote plays in London in the 1600s:

> Make Sacred euen his styrrop.
>   <sub>*Timon of Athen*, a1616 (Shakespeare).</sub>

This example may be from earlier than your play, but it’s not even the earliest known example of *even* in this sense. For that, we must look almost 100 years further back:

> All secretes knowe they, even the very thoughtes of mennes hertes.
>   <sub>*The obedience of a Christen man*, 1528 (Tyndale)</sub>

In other words, you can use *even* here without it being an anachronism.

Comment: Thank you most exceedingly and sincerely--you have answered me dearly.